# Git rebase interactive with GUI

Tags: git, git-gui

When we do `git rebase -i master`, it will come to the message where we need to put which commit to `squash` or `pick` and etc. Only then, it can proceed & complete the `git rebase -i`.

My problem is for most of the PC, it will show the message in the command window and we need to do the changes in it and do some command to proceed with it. This is kind of troublesome for me because one of my PC is able to do changes of the message via Git GUI.

[image]

On that PC, when I do `git rebase -i master` on command prompt window, it will popup the Git GUI where I can directly modify the message, save it by clicking on the save icon and close it. The Git on command prompt window will automatically proceed and finish the `rebase -i` job.

How can I set the git to show up GUI on those PC that don't?

Comment: To what "GUI" are you referring?  Are you saying that on certain of your computers you don't have the Git bash installed?

Comment: What do your gitconfigs look like? Do you define a visual tool? And what is your editor? The files are at `/etc/gitconfig`, `~/.gitconfig` and in you project at `.git/config`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question with the printscreen of the "GUI" I am referring to. How can I set to get that GUI appear on other PC?

Comment: I would advise you to stick with the Git bash tool.  It was designed with your use case in mind, and every version of Git should com with a bash.